# NodeJS application start error

Tags: node.js

When i try to start my app i see the following error. How can i fix it?

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 13.
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/okoz/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: I'd try `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`. After that, do you still have the problem?

Comment: After thai have error when i do npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/home/okoz/package.json'
...

Comment: fixed!
I unistalled unstable nodejs version, change it to v0.26 and reinstalled all modules.